# Delegate method is not fired- iOS

Tags: ios, delegates

I have one tabcontroller and it has two segments. One of them is UserInfo, another one is UserAvatar. Once user put into his info, then click on done button and go to mainview, or user could also choose his profile avatar and then click on click button and then could go to mainView. However, evethough I run by code with debug mode, it runs into done button, but in my userinfo view, delegeta method is not fired!

in my Main header file, I declared my protocol is as follow:

```
@protocol MyUserInfoAvatarViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)userInfoEditingDone:(id)sender;
@end

@protocol MyUserInfoSettingsViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)userInfoEditingDone:(id)sender;
@end
```

in my main.m file, my delegate method

```
- (void)userInfoEditingDone:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"Hello");
}
```

MyUserInfoAvatarViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NEATMainViewController.h"

@interface UserInfoAvatarViewController : UIViewController <ThumbImageViewDelegate > {
    id __unsafe_unretained flipDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id <MyUserInfoAvatarViewControllerDelegate>
```

flipDelegate;
 in the following responding
    in MyUserInfoAvatarViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    // Tell the root view to flip back over to the main view
    [self.flipDelegate userInfoEditingDone:self];
}
```

MyUserInfoSettingsViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "NEATMainViewController.h"
    @interface UserInfoSettingsViewController : UIViewController {
        id __unsafe_unretained flipDelegate;
    }

    @property (nonatomic,unsafe_unretained) id <MyUserInfoSettingsViewControllerDelegate> flipDelegate;
```

in the following is not calling my delegate method.. MyUserInfoSettingsViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(done:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = btn;
}
- (void)done:(id)sender {

    // Tell the root view to flip back over to the main view
    [self.flipDelegate userInfoEditingDone:self];

}
```

Comment: How you set the delegate ?

Comment: Where do you set delegate & Where do you define it?

Comment: Could you please make it more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you `flipDelegate` is `nil` and more over you have defined delegate method in `main.m` which I think doesn't have any class which implements your protocol.

Comment: Could you please look at my updated code and elaborate your answer little bit.?

Comment: Your update is the same what I thought. Why the hell you need delegate in main.m? As I said you have to set your delegate as it's still `nil`. e.g. `myUserInfoSettingsViewControllerObject.flipDelegate = self`

Comment: Thanks a lot Kumar! It works now. I have mistakenly commented out that part.

Answer (score 1):

Check were you missed. It should like this for example say `WeatherAPI` class :

```
@protocol WeatherAPIDelegate <NSObject>

 -(void)weatherData:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictData;

@end

@interface WeatherAPI : NSObject
{
  id <WeatherAPIDelegate>delegate;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong)id <WeatherAPIDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Call `delegate` method like this in `WeatherAPI` :

```
[delegate weatherData:dictWeatherInfo];
```

Now implement in say `ViewController`:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<WeatherAPIDelegate>
{

}
```

Implement `WeatherAPIDelegate` method in `ViewController` :

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark WeatherAPIDelegate Method

-(void)weatherData:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictData
{

}
```

When intializing `WeatherAPI` in `ViewController`

```
WeatherAPI *objWeatherAPI = [[WeatherAPI alloc]init];
[objWeatherAPI setDelegate:self];
```